# Key path value type 'Data.Element.ID' cannot be converted to contextual type 'ID'

Tags: swift, swift-keypath

I am getting the error `Key path value type 'Data.Element.ID' cannot be converted to contextual type 'ID'` when trying to create the initializer in the extension below for when the data which is passed contains elements which already inherit from Identifiable.

```
struct List<Data, ID> where Data: RandomAccessCollection, ID: Hashable {
    private let data: [Data.Element]
    private let id: KeyPath<Data.Element, ID>

    init(data: Data, id: KeyPath<Data.Element, ID>) {
        self.data = data.map { $0 }
        self.id = id
    }
}

extension List where Data.Element: Identifiable {
    init(data: Data) {
        self.data = data.map { $0 }
        self.id = \Data.Element.id // Compilation Error: Key path value type 'Data.Element.ID' cannot be converted to contextual type 'ID'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Data.Element.ID` isn't guaranteed to be of type `List.ID`. You can fix this by adding another type type constraint.

```
extension List where Data.Element: Identifiable, Data.Element.ID == ID {
    init(data: Data) {
        self.data = data.map { $0 }
        self.id = \.id
    }
}
```